# Spawning Minecraft Wither Skeletons with Iron Swords

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I can't figure out how to spawn a wither skeleton with an iron sword in creative. I have tried spawning them, then throwing an iron sword at them, I have tried spawning multiple ones to see if it is a random thing, but I just can't get it to work. Any help would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `/summon` command, either in chat or in a command block. To spawn a wither skeleton with an iron sword, you would do:

```
/summon Skeleton ~3 ~3 ~3 {Equipment:[{id:iron_sword},{},{},{},{}],SkeletonType:1}
```

Which will spawn the wither skeleton 3 blocks relative to where the command was executed I believe.

Comment: Actually, I tried that, and it didn't work... It just said "Unable to summon object".

Comment: I seem to have forgotten to put in two capitals. Corrected it.